# How to create Date into Hex valid to utif8?

Tags: vba, hex

in my case this is the code for VBA to convert the value into hex then hex validated into utif8, but I have an error it missing the 0 value to make it correct, how to do this?

this is vba print:

```
?Hex(2) & Hex(Len("04-01-2022 20:06")) & CreateHex ("04-01-2022 20:06")
21030342D30312D323032322032303A3036
```

here is the image after test, need the 0 at the beginning

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Format`:

```
? Format(Hex(2), "00") & Format(Hex(Len("04-01-2022 20:06")), "00") & CreateHex("04-01-2022 20:06")

021030342D30312D323032322032303A3036
```